# iOS7 UITextView with multiple paragraph styles from file

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, textkit

I am working on an in-app guide for my app where I want to layout some headings and paragraphs of text that support Dynamic Type.

What is the simplest method to with a single UITextView? (The text is Preferably loaded from a separate text file).

There is a lot of approaches to this:

- UIWebViews (over kill??)
- UITextView and NSAttributedString?
- Text Kit - which seems cumbersome for this simple task?

[image: Example of desired layout/functionality]

Comment: You can do pretty decent formatting and embedded images with NSAttributedStrings and UITextView - see here for more details http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/

Comment: Btw you can use RTF format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView is by far the simplest solution for this problem.  You can create the html file as a separate file in your project and load it from the bundle at runtime.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:file baseURL:baseURL];
```

Using the baseURL trick will allow you to even use  inside the html and have it find the images in your app bundle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the baseURL trick! I will get back to you when I know which solution to go with.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `UITextView` should give you what you need. Read the text from your file and set the font according to the category size determined by the user. Since iOS7, you can load a simple HTML file as an attributed string using `initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:`, so you can set simple styles and text inside the file. Use `font:-apple-system-headline;`, `font:-apple-system-subheadline;` and `font:-apple-system-body;` as your font in the HTML to get the correct font in the attributed string when reading an HTML file.

You can listen for `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` notifications to hear when the user has changed his preferred category and set your font or reload your data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot - does it support <img> tags, or is that limited to only UIWebViews?

Comment: `img` is not handled well when converting from HTML to attributed strings unless the images are inlined using base64. For small images, that is OK, but for larger ones it becomes problematic.